# How does SQL covering index work?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I know, when we use a covering index, sql server uses only index seek(nonclustered) or index scan (nonclustered) operator in execution plan without retrieving data by lookup operator. But why is it possible not to look up values in clustered index? Nonclustered index doesn't store data on leaf level so regardless the number of columns it contains it has to ask clustered index to return data rows so it should be lookup operator in execution plan. Am I right? I've read https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/ and other articles but there is no explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any index, at all levels, stores the values for the column(s) defining that index's key. In addition, at the leaf level of the non-clustered index, the leaves store the values for any additional column(s) which are part of the clustered index key<sup>1</sup> and were not part of the non-clustered index key, because that is how the clustered index lookup is then performed.

If the only column(s) that the query needs to retrieve are either part of the non-clustered index key or are part of the clustered index key then we've already obtained all of those column values by navigating the non-clustered index.

Queries, in general, are not trying to retrieve *rows*, only row values from *particular* columns.

---

As an analogy, consider that you're running a census for an entire town, and are storing all of the data and physical cards. These cards contain the person's name, address, date of birth, current occupation, etc. Assume further that every individual has a unique address and so you decide to store all of these cards in address order, in a big box file. This is your clustered index.

You frequently want to locate people based on their names. So you create another set of index cards that tell you, for any particular combination of surname and firstname all of the addresses at which someone with that name resides. You put these cards in a second box file and sort them by surname, firstname values. This is your non-clusered index.

Finally, suppose your task is to identify the street on which all people with the surname `Radish` live. You can obviously use your non-clustered index to identify all of the people with the surname `Radish`. But remember, the cards in this secondary index gives you the addresses for these people. If our only task is to identify their street, we already have that information at hand. There's no need for us to go and look up all of the original census cards, containing all kinds of information that we've *not* been asked for, just to complete this query.

---

<sup>1</sup>And since 2012, any additional columns identified in an `INCLUDE` clause for the index definition.

Comment: From Technet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177484(v=sql.105).aspx: "The leaf layer of a nonclustered index is made up of index pages instead of data pages...SQL Server retrieves the data row by searching the clustered index using the clustered index key stored in the leaf row of the nonclustered index." Look at the illustration at the bottom of page. Nonclustered index doesn't have rows of data only index rows.

Comment: @lukaszwinski - it doesn't **need** the rows - only values from particular columns. And if those values are already included in the index structure, there's no need to go and look up the complete row just to obtain those values again. That's the whole point of the index being covering. If every index use needed to perform a clustered index lookup, the concept of a covering index (and `INCLUDE`) would be meaningless.

Comment: @lukaszwinski - and if you follow the link from your page to [Index with Included Columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806(v=sql.105).aspx) this is confirmed - "Performance gains are achieved because the query optimizer can locate all the column values within the index; table or clustered index data is not accessed... "

Comment: Included option was clear to me from the beginning. I did not understand how covering worked when we didn't create nonclustered index with 'included' option but the query was covered.

Comment: @lukaszwinski - because all that `INCLUDE` did was to extend the feature that already contained the clustered index key.

Answer (score 0):

Since covering index includes all the SELECT items of the query, there is no need to go to table data and try to read from data files. The data you try to read is already contained in the Covering Index.

So you either read all covering index by index scan or you directly read by using index seek.

Comment: Do you even know nonclustered index architecture and b-tree structure?Nonclustred index cannot return data directly because of its design- it keeps RID or clustered index key on leaf level, not queried data rows.

Comment: Last time I queried a table for a value that was only in an index, the only thing it used in the query plan was the index