# Why is Salary >0 not causing a table / index scan

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-execution-plan

I have a test table for this exercise:

```
CREATE DATABASE QueryTest
GO
USE QueryTest

CREATE TABLE Person
(
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    FirstName   NVARCHAR(50),
    SurName     NVARCHAR(50),
    Salary      MONEY
)

INSERT INTO Person
SELECT  TOP 2000
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        RAND(CAST( NEWID() AS varbinary)) *100000
FROM    [AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[Person]
ORDER   BY NEWID()

CREATE INDEX IX_Person_Salary ON Person
(
    Salary
)
```

If I run the following, I get a table scan which is what I would expect

```
SELECT Salary FROM Person
```

If I do this, I get an index seek - again fairly expected,

```
SELECT Salary FROM Person WHERE Salary > 270
```

However, If I do this:

```
SELECT Salary FROM Person WHERE Salary > 0
```

I get an index seek (despite it returning all the rows from the table

Furthermore, if I run

```
SELECT Salary FROM Person
SELECT Salary FROM Person WHERE Salary > 0
```

in the same batch, they are both 50% of the batch

What is going on here?
Why is SQL Server using a seek when the WHERE clause if present if all rows will be returned?

Why is the index seek the same cost as the Index scan?

I was under the impression SQL Server would use its statistics to estimate how many rows are to be returned and then plan its execution accordingly. The statistics would tell it that >0 is all the rows and therefore the scan would be less costly in this instance?

Comment: Do you clear buffers and plan cache between executions? Maybe you have ["forced parametrization option"](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2935/sql-server-simple-and-forced-parameterization/) on.

Comment: I would think that this is expected as the engine still has to compare the value of salary to see if it is greater than zero, just like when it compares it to 270

Comment: Should it not be? Its still a seek even though it returns everything, because it still needs to parse the Index. Since a seek only touches rows that qualify and parses all that contain these rows, the cost is proportional to the number of qualifying rows and parses rather than to the total number of rows in the table. This is the case even if everyting is being pulled. Unless I am complete off base.

Comment: I was under the impression SQL Server would use its statistics to estimate how many rows are to be returned and then plan its execution accordingly. The statistics would tell it that >0 is all the rows and therefore the scan would be less costly in this instance?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you have 100k rows and freshly updated statistics?

Comment: Yes!!! GSerg - youve got it. 150k rows and it decided to do a table scan.

Comment: @GSerg However, I still don't understand how, when it was doing a scan, it was the same cost as the seek....

Comment: Small table, fast hard drive, not enough of a difference to jump over the scan threshold?

Comment: I didn't think the cost was based on specific PC hardware?

Comment: You are correct, [it is not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40875/5203).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a couple of years since I asked this but I think I am now in a position to answer my own question. (I also read back some of the other answers which make a bit more sense to me now so apologies if I repeat them below)

Firstly I believe there is a typo / misuse of terminology in my question:

> If I run the following, I get a table scan which is what I would
>   expect

should read

> I get a non-clustered index scan which is what I expect

This is because as the query

```
SELECT Salary FROM Person
```

will scan the narrowest, relevant index, in this case `IX_Person_Salary`

As per [Brent's article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/11/index-scans-not-nearly-bad-might-think/) a scan means we start reading at one end of the index (and in this case, read until the end)

The following query produces an index seek 
`SELECT Salary FROM Person WHERE Salary > 270`

As mentioned in the article above, a seek is basically a scan of an index where we know which row we will start the scan from, it will stop scanning when the values no longer match the predicate (this could be part way through an index or all the way to the end) the `WHERE` clause means we scan that index starting at `Salary = 270` and read all the values from there that are > 270 (IE all of them) If we had a further `AND Salary < n` in our `WHERE` clause, the seek would stop reading once we hit `n` in the index.

`SELECT Salary FROM Person WHERE Salary > 0`
will also cause a seek however, the seek is in effect, a full index scan due to the fact that it will start at Salary > 0 and scan all the values where salary > 0 (IE all of them) This is, in fact the same as the Non-Clustered Index scan on the `SELECT Salary FROM Person` query which can be verified by the actual number of rows read on the two queries being the same in their respective plans

As the estimated number of rows (and therefore costs) on `SELECT Salary FROM Person WHERE Salary > 0` and `SELECT Salary FROM Person`  are the same, the plans will both cost 50% (as the cost of the plans are the estimated cost, even on an actual plan)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things going on here:

Firstly: No table scan because your Data is in a Non-Clusterd index (think of it as a smaller -ordered - copy of the table that contains only Salary) It's quicker to get all the data required from the index.

Secondly: > 0 thing and performance split.

Your Column definition for [Salary] allows for NULLs. When SQL Produces an execution plan it is assuming NULLs may be in the table so cannot explicitly predict that >0 will return all values. SQL 'Plans' to do a Seek, but ends up 'Actually' doing a Scan. The Actual Execution plan IS the Estimated execution plan but with additional metrics.

The code demo below shows this behaviour with a 52% 48% split on my environment.

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP1
(
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    FirstName   NVARCHAR(50),
    SurName     NVARCHAR(50),
    Salary      MONEY
)

CREATE TABLE #TMP2
(
    ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    FirstName   NVARCHAR(50),
    SurName     NVARCHAR(50),
    Salary      MONEY NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO #TMP1
SELECT  'xxxxx','xxxxx',RAND(CAST( NEWID() AS varbinary)) *100000
GO 2000


INSERT INTO #TMP2
SELECT FirstName,SurName,Salary FROM #TMP1


CREATE INDEX IX_Person_Salary ON #TMP1
(
    Salary
)
CREATE INDEX IX_Person_Salary ON #TMP2
(
    Salary
)


SELECT Salary FROM #TMP1 WHERE Salary > 0
SELECT Salary FROM #TMP2 WHERE Salary > 0
```

Update

Check the histogram for your index, if it starts at 0 then you'll need to do >=0 to get a full scan.

Comment: Still showing a seek

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1BVaDh0f

Answer (score 0):

The query retrieves a single column `Person` only:

```
SELECT Salary FROM Person WHERE Salary > 0
```

At the same time there is only one condition `Salary > 0` using the same column `Person`.

If there is an index on the salary column, then it is cheaper to scan only this index instead on the whole table. This is so called [covering index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48059124/how-does-sql-covering-index-work) for this query, because the index contains all information required to perform this query, the database reads all needed information from the index file without reaching the table.

Comment: I would also expect an index scan of a covering index, but the OP is seeing index seeks.